# CAShaperLayer outlook change at initial point?

Tags: ios, cashapelayer

I have made the Circle like this in my iOS Demo App.

http://www.pastebin.ca/3119326

like below image

[image]

```
I want a needle shape crossing 90 degree to line which is being made. like below image, which I am unable to find via code.
```

[image]
How can achieve this, any suggestion.

Thanks.

Comment: How can I use UIBezierPath to make a vertical line before circle draw?

Answer (score -1):

Pseudo Code/Real Code, here's how the layout would work, just a quick sample:

a line:

```
UIBezierPath* bezierPath = UIBezierPath.bezierPath;
[bezierPath moveToPoint: CGPointMake(43.5, 30.5)];
[bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(166.5, 74.5) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(166.5, 74.5) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(166.5, 74.5)];
[UIColor.blackColor setStroke];
bezierPath.lineWidth = 1;
[bezierPath stroke];

CAShapeLayer * firstNameCorners = [CAShapeLayer layer];
[firstNameCorners setPath:bezierPath];
[[self.view layer] addSublayer:firstNameCorners];
```

run spin animation:

```
- (void)spinUntilYouThrowUp:(CAShapeLayer*)shapeLayer duration:(CGFloat)duration rotations:(CGFloat)rotations repeat:(float)repeat;
{
    CABasicAnimation* rotationAnimation;
    rotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
    rotationAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: M_PI * 2.0 * rotations * duration ];
    rotationAnimation.duration = duration;
    rotationAnimation.cumulative = YES;
    rotationAnimation.repeatCount = repeat;
    [shapeLayer addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"rotationAnimation"];
}
```

Comment: check this answer again, I didn't declare the method VARs the right way, should work for the most part now

Comment: of course it's not working specifically for your case, that's why I said this is an example, you have to think through this and tweak it but this is how you do ti